# Android Click event not working in Ionic 3 firebase push notifications?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I am using ***cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated*** this plugin for push notification. Notification receiving on top of the notification bar but when I click on it it will redirect to respected app but ***if (data.wasTapped)*** this is not firing what to do now ?

This is my notification payload.

```
{
blogID: "2601"
body: ""
click_action: "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
description: ""
deviceId: "eGKYSXRYkqY:APA91...."
redirect: "BlogDetails"
title: "Post created successfully"
wasTapped: false
}
```

Here is the notification code in app.component.ts file

```
 this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data.wasTapped) {
        console.log(":::Tapped::::", data);
        // Here click event not working 
} else {
   // Notification received in ForeGround 
    // This is working fine notification receiving 
}
```

I also try with this payload mention in github repo

```
{
  "token": "[FCM token]",
  "notification":{
  "title":"Post created successfully",
  "body":"",
  "sound":"default",
 },
 "data":{"redirect":"BlogDetails","blogID":2609}
 ,
 "android": {
 "notification": {
  "icon":"fcm_push_icon",
  "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
   }
 }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: share your notification code.

Comment: Hi added notification code from my end.

Comment: Hi Any body if you are looking for solution, Try with different payload formate. Exact payload will post as a solution for this once I get time to find out from my project.